# How to create list field type in sonata admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

I'm using Symfony 2.3 and newest SonataAdminBundle. It's possible to create editable fields in list view with SonataAdminBundle? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('title')
            ->addIdentifier('artist')
            ->add('createDate')
            ->add('changeDate')
            ->add('missing', null, array('editable' => true))
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'view' => array(),
                    'edit' => array(),
                    'delete' => array()
                )
            ))
        ;
```

Notice the array('editable' => true). For booleans this works, I'm not sure for other fields.

Comment: Yes, it's work only for boolean fields:( But, I need, that it work's for string and orther fields too, for example like in django admin.

Comment: This is not possible by default. What you can do is write a custom view for the list view (extend from the base list view).

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking in the same direction, but suggested that the problem can be solved more gracefully. I'll leave this implementation.